# Converting JSON to Object fails - Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using the API of www.textlocal.in, which returns a JSON formatted object.

**JSON**

```
{  
   "warnings":[  
      {  
         "message":"Number is in DND",
         "numbers":"917000000000"
      }
   ],
   "balance":900,
   "batch_id":311110011,
   "cost":1,
   "num_messages":1,
   "message":{  
      "num_parts":1,
      "sender":"TXTLCL",
      "content":"Test1"
   },
   "receipt_url":"",
   "custom":"",
   "inDND":[  
      "917000000000"
   ],
   "messages":[  
      {  
         "id":"1350123781",
         "recipient":918819437284
      }
   ],
   "status":"success"
}
```

**My code with which I'm trying to parse the JSON:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<jsonToObj[]>>(richTextBox1.Text);
}

public class jsonToObj
{
    public warnings[] warnings { get; set; }

    public int balance { get; set; }
    public int batch_id { get; set; }
    public int cost { get; set; }
    public int num_messages { get; set; }
    public message message { get; set; }
    public string receipt_url { get; set; }
    public string custom { get; set; }
    public messages[] messages { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}


public class warnings
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string numbers { get; set; }
}

public class messages
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int recipient { get; set; }
}

public class message
{
    public int num_part { get; set; }
    public string sender { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
}
```

**I'm getting an exception with the following message:**

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WindowsFormsApp1.Form2+jsonToObj[]]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'warnings', line 1, position
>   12.'

Comment: Think you just need `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<jsonToObj[]>>(richTextBox1.Text);` to be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonToObj>(richTextBox1.Text);` based on your provided JSON

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you have to figure out what your API returns.

Right now you're trying to parse a `List` of `jsonToObj` `Arrays` (`List<jsonToObj[]>`). You have to decide whether to use a `jsonToObj[]` or `List<jsonToObj>` or a simple `jsonToObj` which your API provides now:

```
var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonToObj>(richTextBox1.Text);
```

But this then throws:

> JSON integer 918819437284 is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'messages[0].recipient', line 25, position 33."

So make sure you use a `Long` for that.

```
public class messages
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public long recipient { get; set; }
}
```

Furthermore you *can* add `inDND` to your `jsonToObj` class if you need the info:

```
public class jsonToObj
{
  ...
  public string[] inDND { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

[image: Deserialized JSON]

Answer (score 1):

Based on string you class structure should be like this :

```
public class Warning
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string numbers { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int num_parts { get; set; }
    public string sender { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
}

public class Message2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public long recipient { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Warning> warnings { get; set; }
    public int balance { get; set; }
    public int batch_id { get; set; }
    public int cost { get; set; }
    public int num_messages { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
    public string receipt_url { get; set; }
    public string custom { get; set; }
    public List<string> inDND { get; set; }
    public List<Message2> messages { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

---

It looks like your class structure is not proper, Make use of visual studio and generate C# class from json string and then using that generated class try to deserialize class.

[image]

Read : [Visual Studio Generate Class From JSON or XML](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2015/07/introduction-below-article-is-on-one-of.html)

Comment: @DurgeshPadha - change your array to list , as per you string generated class have list not array

Comment: @DurgeshPadha - try out class structure given, it must work

Answer (score 0):

I simulated your problem and made the following changes that worked:

1. Change the method that deserializes to this:

   ```
   var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonToObj>(richTextBox1.Text);
   ```

   The result of the JSON you receive is not a `List`, so it will not work to deserialize to `List<>`.
2. The `recipient` property of the `messages` class receives values larger than an integer, so it must be transformed into a long like this:

   ```
   public long recipient { get; set; }
   ```

These changes solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a very old post, still thought of answering.

First of all, your Json data is singular which means, either

```
var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<jsonToObj[]>>(richTextBox1.Text);
```

or

```
var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<jsonToObj>>(richTextBox1.Text);
```

may not work for you.

You can either try:

```
var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonToObj>(richTextBox1.Text);
```

or

```
enclose the data with [ and ], which would do the trick.
```

make sure your parsing single object vs list of objects.